# Recursive constructor from array of generic elements

Tags: java, recursion, constructor

I have this assingment where I have to implement a single linked list class in java, but, it's required to be implemented entirely with recursive functions, even the constructor.

The constructor given in the project provided by the teacher receives an array of n generic elements with the 3-dot notation (T ... elements) and after scratching my head a little bit (I've never done a recursive constructor) I've come up with something that obviously doesn't work:

```
public SingleLinkedListImpl(T ... elements) {
    if(elements.length<=1){
        header = new Node<T>(elements[0]);
    } else {
        addLast(elements[0]);
        elements=Arrays.copyOfRange(elements, 1, elements.length-1);
        this(elements);
    }
}
```

The IDE im currently working with, says this cant be done because if I refer to the constructor with this, inside the constructor itself it MUST be the first statement in the function.

How do I proceed with this issue?

BTW: I cant use anything from the Collections API

Comment: You could try overloading the constructor.

Comment: I've tryed implementing and using a SimpleLinkedListImpl(T element) in the recursive calls but the error persist.

Answer (score 3):

“Recursive constructor” doesn’t equate to calling `this()`, but rather calling `new SingleLinkedListImpl()`.

Also, `this` *is* the head, rather than *has* a head.

Assuming your class has `next` and `value` fields, in pseudo code:

- if the array is empty, throw an `IllegalArgumentException`
- set `value` to the first element of the array
- if there is more than 1 element in the array, set the value of `next` to `new SingleLinkedListImpl(<elements 1 to n>)`

To call it:

```
SingleLinkedListImpl<Integer> head = new SingleLinkedListImpl<>(3, 1, 4, 1, 5); // for example
```